# XAMPPをインストール後、Mysqlの文字コードの設定をしたらエラーが出続けます

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

お世話になります。

XAMPPを始めようと、インストールして起動させるまでは何事もなく成功していたのですが、
文字コードをUTF-8に変更しようとmy.iniを変更したところ、下記のようなエラーが出続けるようになりました。
必死に自分で追おうとしたのですが、すみません、挫折しました。

```
Warning in .\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli.php#184
 mysqli_query(): MySQL server has gone away

Backtrace

.\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli.php#184: mysqli_query(
,
string 'SHOW TABLES FROM `phpmyadmin`;',
integer 0,
)
.\libraries\DatabaseInterface.php#267: PMA\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli->realQuery(
string 'SHOW TABLES FROM `phpmyadmin`;',
,
integer 1,
)
.\libraries\DatabaseInterface.php#1639: PMA\libraries\DatabaseInterface->tryQuery(
string 'SHOW TABLES FROM `phpmyadmin`;',
,
integer 1,
boolean false,
)
.\libraries\DatabaseInterface.php#327: PMA\libraries\DatabaseInterface->fetchResult(
string 'SHOW TABLES FROM `phpmyadmin`;',
NULL,
integer 0,
,
integer 1,
)
.\libraries\relation.lib.php#1928: PMA\libraries\DatabaseInterface->getTables(
string 'phpmyadmin',
,
)
.\libraries\common.inc.php#922: PMA_fixPMATables(
string 'phpmyadmin',
boolean false,
)
.\db_structure.php#15: require_once(.\libraries\common.inc.php)
Warning in .\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli.php#184
 mysqli_query(): Error reading result set's header

Backtrace

.\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli.php#184: mysqli_query(
,
string 'SHOW TABLES FROM `phpmyadmin`;',
integer 0,
)
.\libraries\DatabaseInterface.php#267: PMA\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli->realQuery(
string 'SHOW TABLES FROM `phpmyadmin`;',
,
integer 1,
)
.\libraries\DatabaseInterface.php#1639: PMA\libraries\DatabaseInterface->tryQuery(
string 'SHOW TABLES FROM `phpmyadmin`;',
,
integer 1,
boolean false,
)
.\libraries\DatabaseInterface.php#327: PMA\libraries\DatabaseInterface->fetchResult(
string 'SHOW TABLES FROM `phpmyadmin`;',
NULL,
integer 0,
,
integer 1,
)
.\libraries\relation.lib.php#1928: PMA\libraries\DatabaseInterface->getTables(
string 'phpmyadmin',
,
)
.\libraries\common.inc.php#922: PMA_fixPMATables(
string 'phpmyadmin',
boolean false,
)
.\db_structure.php#15: require_once(.\libraries\common.inc.php)
```

参考にしたのは、下記のサイト様です。

https://www.adminweb.jp/xampp/mysql/index4.html

尚、使用したXAMPPのバージョンは『xampp-win32-7.1.7-0-VC14-installer』です。

サイト様の記述の通り、指定のコメントを削除し、default-character-set=utf8の
文をそれぞれに追加しました。

他に変更したところは一切ありません。
もちろん、データベースの再起動も行っています。

対処方法をお教えください。お願いいたします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自分もさっき全く同じものに引っかかりました。

`#init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'`

ですが、参考サイトに

> init-connect='SET NAMES utf8' の部分は「\」を除去しています

とあるので、utf8\'をutf8'にしてよしOK,と思ったのですが、よくよくサンプルコードを見ると

`init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'`

ってなってるんですよね。という訳で、'SET NAMES utf8'にしなきゃいけないよ、取るべき'\'は二つありますよ、という話でした。

Comment: cubickさん、編集ありがとうございます。最初から誤解生まないように書きましょうって話ですね。お手数おかけして申し訳ありません。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 質問者です。今時になってしまい、大変申し訳ありません。解決しなかったため、しばらく離れておりました。ご指摘の通りでした。修正したところ、正しく動作いたしました。

Answer (score 0):

実際に変更した my.ini の内容を提示すると期待する回答が得られやすいかと思います。

Google で「[mysql server has gone away xampp](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=mysql+server+has+gone+away+xampp)」と検索すると以下のような対策が見当たりました。

状況から察するに、 init-connect を再コメントアウトするか、 php.ini で default_charset を指定するとよいのではないでしょうか。

#### max_allowed_packet

[Solution to MySQL error #2006 in XAMPP](http://eppand.com/solution-to-mysql-error-2006-in-xampp/)

1. :¥xampp¥mysql¥bin¥my.ini を開く。
2. max_allowed_packet の値を増やす。デフォルトは 1M で、 10M に増やす。
3. my.ini ファイルを保存する。
4. XAMPP の MySQL と　Apache サーバーを再起動する。

---

#### init-connect

[MySQLでMySQL server has gone awayエラー - Programming Academy Tech Note](http://pgacademy.hateblo.jp/entry/2013/06/08/151517)

```
init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
```

が NG だった

---

#### default_charset

[utf 8 - MySQL server has gone away due to error CHARACTER SET 'utf8' - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40379322/mysql-server-has-gone-away-due-to-error-character-set-utf8)

D:¥xampp¥php¥php.ini ファイルの PHP のデフォルトのキャラクターの default_charset = "UTF-8" のコメントを外すと動作する。

```
; PHP's built-in default is text/html
; http://php.net/default-mimetype
default_mimetype = "text/html"

; PHP's default character set is set to empty.
; http://php.net/default-charset
;default_charset = "UTF-8"
```

D:¥xampp¥mysql¥bin¥my.ini ファイルにもいくつかの変更を加える。

```
## UTF 8 Settings
#init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8
skip-character-set-client-handshake
character_sets-dir="D:/xampp/mysql/share/charsets"
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。連休のため、お礼が遅れてしまい、申し訳ありませんでした。ですが、いただきましたとおりに修正をしてみたのですが、状況は何も変わりませんでした。iniファイルの内容は、確認してみましたが、既存からご指摘通りの内容でした。唯一『max_allowed_packet』は1Mから10Mに修正しましたが、特に改善された点はありませんでした。引き続きご助力いただければ幸いです。

Comment: 確認が遅くなりました。状況は何も変わらないということで残念です。ただ、状況が変わらない、だけでは誰も助けようがないので、回答に記載の通り、現在の my.ini の内容を掲載してみてはどうでしょうか。